# sizeof(*this) and struct inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct, sizeof

Say I have a `struct` like the following:

```
struct ParentStruct
{
   virtual void XYZ()
   {
      getSize(sizeof(*this));
   }
   int memberX;
}
```

And another `struct` which inherits the parent struct:

```
struct ChildStruct : public ParentStruct
{
    int memberY;
    int memberZ;
}
```

Assuming `sizeof(int) == 4`, is it possible to have a value of *12* passed to the function `getSize()` when called from the child struct (I am currently getting a value of *4*)?

I would prefer not to have to overwrite `XYZ()` in all the sub-structs, as I will have many of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use templates to get around this problem:

```
template <typename Child>
struct ParentStruct
{
   virtual void XYZ()
   {
      getSize(sizeof(Child));
   }
   int memberX;
}

struct ChildStruct : public ParentStruct<ChildStruct>
{
    int memberY;
    int memberZ;
}
```

This way you tell the parent struct who its children are - it's not a super clean solution but it gets the work done and avoids repeating the getSize code.

Comment: But then you can't make generic things like vector, `vector<ParentStruct>` won't work without type parameter. many good things in inheritance are lost in this.

Comment: @Dani: Simply add a superbase like my example does and everything's fine.

Answer (score 7):

As others say, the type of `this` is the static type of the class its used in. However, you can do some template trickery:

```
struct Parent{
    virtual void xyz(){ getSize(sizeof(Parent)); }
    int mem1;
};

template<class D>
struct Intermediate : public Parent{
    virtual void xyz(){ getSize(sizeof(D)); }
};

struct Child : public Intermediate<Child>{
    int mem2, mem3;
};
```

This should give the wanted effect.

Comment: `virtual void xyz(){ getSize(sizeof(parent)); }` Hug? Pure virtual?

Comment: @curious: Why? He may have simple `Parent` objects alongside child objects, accessing both through `Parent` pointers. Can't really tell from what we're shown.

Comment: True, we are really missing contextual information. (What the hell are you trying to do?)

Answer (score 1):

Type type of `this` is always the static class type, so `sizeof(*this)` is always `sizeof(ParentStruct)`.
(Consider: how would `sizeof` remain a constant expression if the type of `this` was not static?)

If you tel us what you're trying to do, we can suggest more maintainable alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `sizeof` in this case only knows the size of the *static type* of `*this` (i.e. `ParentStruct`), not its type at runtime (`ChildStruct`).  It doesn't matter that `XYZ()` is declared `virtual` here.

Answer (score -1):

you are getting the size of the base struct you did not overload it in the child

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, but your answer doesn't make sense.  What would you overload in the child?  `sizeof`?  You can't overload that.  Also, answering in complete sentences usually helps.

Comment: the virtual method is not overloaded in the child struct so the method is sizeof the base struct.  virtual void XYZ()

Comment: But then you'd need to duplicate code, which is generally undesirable.

Comment: No, that is NOT duplicate code.  Subclassing and overloading is what inheritance is ALL ABOUT!!!!  And since it is a virtual method when you overload it you can force the call into the subclass even when the subclass object is being held in a parent pointer.

Comment: You'd need two implementations of the `XYZ` method, and the body of each would be the same: `getSize(sizeof(*this));`.  How is that not duplicate code?  Now, if you suggested adding a separate virtual method that simply returned `sizeof *this` that you implemented in the base and child classes, that'd be better (although it'd still be error-prone since you'd be relying on each derived class to reimplement it).